# Encrypted message doesn't appear on page

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-4

I'm using [pgp-2fa](https://github.com/hardest1/pgp-2fa) and on my local is working great. I've trying it now on the host but doesn't show the encrypted message.

The way is working is

```
$key = DB::table('users')->select('pgp_key')->where('user_id', '=', $data['user_id'])->first();
$pgp = new pgp_2fa();
$msg = '';

$pgp->generateSecret();
$enc = $pgp->encryptSecret($key->pgp_key);

return View::make('users.auth', ['enc'=> $enc]);
```

Here I've selected users public pgp key from his profile and encrypt the message which then he must decrypt with his private key.

When I `var_dump($enc);` I've received

`bool(false)`

and `var_dump($pgp);` 
`object(pgp_2fa)#336 (1) { ["secret":"pgp_2fa":private]=> string(15) "603893251905515" }`

which is correct `string(15) "603893251905515"`. The problem is in my view I don't see `$enc` because it's returning `bool(false)`.

This is what I have in the view

```
<pre>{{ $enc }}</pre>
```

Again: This is working great on my local but can't figured it out why doesn't work here. Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

`var_dump($key);` also return correct key from database for this user. I'm not copied whole key because is to long:

```
object(stdClass)#353 (1) { ["pgp_key"]=> string(1756) "-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK----- Version: GnuPG v1 m............
```

UPDATE2: `pgp-2fa.php`

```
class pgp_2fa {
    private $secret;

// Generate safe hash of unencrypted secret, push it to the session and save unencrypted secret locally


public function generateSecret(){

    // Generate unencrypted secret

    $secret = generateSecretKey();

    // Hash the secret with bcrypt

    $secret_hash = password_hash($secret, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    // Save within the session
    Session::set('pgp-secret-hash', $secret_hash);
    $this->secret = $secret;
}

// Encrypt secret with PGP public key

public function encryptSecret($public_key){

    // Set GnuPG homedir to /tmp

    putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");

    // Create new GnuPG instance

    $gpg = new gnupg();

    // Import given public key

    $key = $gpg->import($public_key);

    // Add imported key for encryption

    $gpg->addencryptkey($key['fingerprint']);

    // Encrypt the secret to a PGP message

    $enc = $gpg->encrypt($this->secret);

    // Clear the encryption key

    $gpg->clearencryptkeys();

    // Return  the PGP message

    return $enc;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: Yes, no errors at all..

Comment: You should dump `$key` too.

Comment: What versions of php are you using on your localhost and web server?

Comment: @PatrickQ updated with dump of key. Correct..

Comment: server version `PHP Version 7.0.12-1~dotdeb+8.1` .. local host version `PHP Version 5.6.27-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1`. gnupg on localhost `GPGme Version = 1.6.0` on web server `GPGme Version = 1.7.1` because 1.7.1 is recommended for php7

Comment: Actually this which is came from gnupg `string(15) "603893251905515"` should be encrypted... so gnupg return correct string but is not encrypted.

Comment: Added pgp-2fa.php file (part of it) to question if need...

Comment: Could be a problem with `GnuPG homedir` if you don't have permission or something..